# what is difference between spring framework and spring roo

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-roo

Can anyone clarify what are the differences between Spring Framework, Spring ROO, and Spring MVC ? I am really puzzled by these similar terms and cannot mangage find an answer.

Comment: Spring MVC is part of the [Spring Framework](http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework). [Spring Roo](http://projects.spring.io/spring-roo/) is a seperate project.

Comment: @M.Deinum But Spring MVC is targeted for building web project right ? just like Spring Roo ?

Comment: No. Spring MVC and Spring Roo have different use cases. Although it is possible to use Spring Roo to generate a web based application (which uses Spring MVC again) it isn't a web framework itself. Spring Roo is a generation framework/tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really easy:

- **Spring Roo** is a DEVELOPMENT-TIME tool, similar to Eclipse, IntelliJ, etc.
- **Spring Framework** is a RUN-TIME framework.

Applications generated with Spring Roo at development time use Spring Framework at run time.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I do not want to be rude, but also from SO tags we know:

- spring

> The Spring Framework is an open source framework for application development on the Java platform. At its core is rich support for component based architectures, and it currently has over a dozen highly integrated modules.

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/spring/info

- spring-mvc

> Based on the Model-View-Controller (MVC) pattern, Spring MVC helps you build web-based applications that are flexible and decoupled from the underlying view technologies.

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/spring-mvc/info

- spring-roo

> Spring Roo is a lightweight tool aimed at developer productivity. Via an intuitive command line interface it supports operations such as Java web project creation, persistence configuration and view scaffolding. Roo creates a Java web project that uses the Spring framework, and leverage some best ...

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/spring-roo/info

---

My own brief description would be: Spring framework is the framework providing some functionalities for example dependency injection. Spring MVC is for creating web projects as you mentioned already. Finally Spring Roo is a tool, that helps you increase productivity, I'd say that instead of manual configuration changes you are using this tool.

Hopefully, this was not too brief...

Comment: thanks a lot. I already read these tag info but still have difficulties understand due to less practical working experiences. Well with your description, can we say Spring MVC is suited for Web applications while Spring ROO is more general purpose ?

Comment: Not exactly. You are correct with MVC - it's used in runtime, while ROO helps you with some project settings and so on, but "Its innovative approach operates entirely at compile-time and is completely compatible with your IDE. Plus because there's no runtime portion, adoption is also simplified and low risk." (http://projects.spring.io/spring-roo/) - roo is not used in runtime...